# How to take a screenshot by passing coordinates and dimensions in Playwright?

Tags: playwright, google-chrome-headless

Is it possible to take a screenshot by passing coordinates and dimensions (like the output of [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)) via [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/)?

Looking at their [screenshots API](https://playwright.dev/docs/screenshots), it seems I need to select a locator first, but the [locator API](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators) doesn't seem to accept coordinates as arguments.

```js
await page.locator('.header').screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the ability to screenshot specific co-ordinates are only available at page level by passing in the PageScreenshotOptions as an option:

```
await page.screenshot({ clip: {height: 100, width: 100, x: 0, y: 0 } });
```